# Component in between row, conditionally on an ngFor loop

Tags: html, angular

I have two components, images and image. Images displays a list of thumbnail images (ThumbnailUrl) like this the following, which effectively creates rows containing columns of up to 4.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3" *ngFor="let image of images | search:search; trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index">
        <app-image [image]="image"></app-image>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the image, I would like to display a full image (SourceUrl). Here's my data model.

```
export class Image {
    constructor(
        public id: Number,
        public Key: string,
        public SourceUrl: string,
        public ThumbnailUrl: string,
        public Tags: string
    ) { }
}
```

What I'd like to do is have up to 4 columns per row. If one of the pictures is clicked, I want a new row to appear after the nearest, 4th column. This would effectively create a clean break so there wouldn't be empty columns in the row above where that image would appear. For example, if the user clicks on the 2nd image, I would like the full image to display in a row below it's row, rather than the next 4 images. The next 4 image thumbnails would instead appear below the source image.

For now, this is working:

public showSourceImage(index: number, thumbImage: Image): boolean {
        // Getting the index of a matching image. sourceImage is an observable that gets sent by the image compoment.
        if (this.sourceImage && thumbImage.id === this.sourceImage.id) {
            // Gets the nearest row based on the selected image so we know where to put the new row
            this.indexToUse = this.getNearestRowIndex(index, 4);
        }

```
    // If the image from the ngFor is where we want to add the image, display the full image after it
    if (this.indexToUse === index) {
        this.indexToUse = -1;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

// Math to determine what the nearest 4th column is based on an index
private getNearestRowIndex(index: number, row: number): number {
    return (Math.ceil((index + 1) / row) * row) - 1;
}
```

That effectively allows me to determine if an image matches the selected image and get the closest 4th column. If the ngFor is on the nearest 4th column, add the image we selected below it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let image of images | search:search; trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index">
        <div class="col s3">
            <app-image [image]="image"></app-image>
        </div>
        <!-- If this image matches the selected image, create an index based on it of the closest 4th column. 
        If this is the index of the 4th closest column, display the sourceImage as a new row. -->
        <div class="row" *ngIf="showSourceImage(i, image)">
            <div class="col s12">
                <img class="responsive-img" src="{{sourceImage.SourceUrl}}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many images are supposed to be in your array? Do you assume to have several rows with 4 columns?

Comment: Can you edit the question with the image data or data format? And, can you be elaborate more on the "I want a new row to appear below those specific 4 columns"? Is that a different image as the variable says or the same image is enlarged and shown?
Please explain your requirement clearly.

Comment: What do you mean by the break in "Based on my reading of the docs and other posts, there's no way to put a break" ?

Comment: I've added clarify to my post, including the typescript data model.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood from your problem, does something like this fix your issue? If you can provide more on the expected behavior for other scenarios like what should happen when the user clicks another image after clicking one, or you want more rows to be added upon subsequent clicking, or should they disappear/replace later etc. I could try to modify it.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s3" *ngFor="let image of images | search:search; trackBy: trackByFn; let i = index">
        <app-image [image]="image" (click)="imageClicked(image)"></app-image>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row" *ngIf="isImageClicked">
    <div class="col s12">
        <app-image [differenceImage]="selectedImage"></app-image>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Inside your Component

```
isImageClicked = false;
selectedImage: <Specify Type of Image you use if you have one>;

imageClicked(image: <Specify Type of Image you use if you have one>) {
 this.isImageClicked = true;
 this.selectedImage = image;
}
```

Comment: The problem is this won't place the image after the nearest, 4th column. If there was a list of 300 images and someone clicked the 1st one, it seems like it'd appear at the very bottom. I've clarified my post for the requirements I was looking for. Thanks!